# logging.BasicConfig() seems not to follow docs

Tags: python, logging

I think the following code should print all messages but it only works if I call BasicConfig:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("log")

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  SHOULD NOT BE NEEDED, YET IT IS.

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(filename)s(%(lineno)d)[%(name)s]: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
print("This print test printed")
print(f"Enabled: {logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)}")
logger.propagate = False
logger.debug("This debug printed")
logger.info("This info printed")
logger.warning("This warning printed")
logger.error("This error printed")
logger.critical("This critical printed")
```

I get that basicConfig controls the root logger, but I'm not using the root logger. Still I am getting this output:

```
This print test printed
Enabled: False
WARNING: scratch.py(15)[log]: This warning printed
ERROR: scratch.py(16)[log]: This error printed
CRITICAL: scratch.py(17)[log]: This critical printed
```

Shouldn't the code above had sidestepped the root logger and let my logger work at whatever level I want it to work at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `setLevel` method of a `logging.StreamHandler` object. When what you want to be calling is `setLevel` method of a `logging.Logger` object.

Changing `handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)` with `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` will make your code behave as you expect, modulo that it will not print the `DEBUG` message because you are asking for `INFO` and above. See (below, I set the level to `DEBUG` to get all the messages):

```py
>>> import logging
>>> 
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("log")
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> 
>>> handler = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s: %(filename)s(%(lineno)d)[%(name)s]: %(message)s")
>>> handler.setFormatter(formatter)
>>> logger.addHandler(handler)
>>> print("This print test printed")
This print test printed
>>> print(f"Enabled: {logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)}")
Enabled: True
>>> logger.propagate = False
>>> logger.debug("This debug printed")
DEBUG: <stdin>(1)[log]: This debug printed
>>> logger.info("This info printed")
INFO: <stdin>(1)[log]: This info printed
>>> logger.warning("This warning printed")
WARNING: <stdin>(1)[log]: This warning printed
>>> logger.error("This error printed")
ERROR: <stdin>(1)[log]: This error printed
>>> logger.critical("This critical printed")
CRITICAL: <stdin>(1)[log]: This critical printed
```

You may have overlooked in [the Logging handlers docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) that `logging.StreamHandler` has a `setLevel` method (this is the reason why your code does not raise an exception), likely because it it is not explicitly mentioned. `logging.StreamHandler` is a subclass of `logging.Handler` (see the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b32d8b4f9bcd2e7d11240b6b9de0262cf8f5e09d/Lib/logging/__init__.py)), and `logging.Handler` has a `setLevel` method (see the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b32d8b4f9bcd2e7d11240b6b9de0262cf8f5e09d/Lib/logging/__init__.py) or the part of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) under "Handler Objects" for more details).

For completeness, the reason why your code prints `WARNING` and above is because it uses the default level, which in this case is `30`, i.e., `WARNING` (you can check this by `logger.getEffectiveLevel()`). You may want to refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) under "Logger Objects" to see why that is the case.

Comment: Thanks! Does the system use the most restrictive level of logger and handler?